# How to get String after a certain character using pattern matching?

Tags: java, regex

```
String tect = "A to B";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("\\b(A.*)\\b");
Matcher mtchr = ptrn.matcher(tr.text()); 
while(mtchr.find()) {
    System.out.println( mtchr.group(1) );
}
```

I am getting output `A to B` but I want `to B`.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can just place the `A` outside of your capturing group.

```
String s  = "A to B";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("A *(.*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // "to B"
}
```

You could also split the string.

```
String s = "A to B";
String[] parts = s.split("A *");
System.out.println(parts[1]); // "to B"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your pattern to use look-behind possitive assertion checking for `A`:

```
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?<=A)(.*)");
```

Comment: That's some scary stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line:

```
String afterA = str.replaceAll(".*?A *", ""),
```